# How to drop a column dataframe (df) in Pandas based on condition if the column is present in df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python code that pulls data from a 3 rd party API.Below is the code.

```
for sub in sublocation_ids:
    city_num_int = sub['id']
    city_num_str = str(city_num_int)
    city_name = sub['name']
    filter_text_new = filter_text.format(city_num_str)
    data = json.dumps({"filters": [filter_text_new], "sort_by":"fb_tw_and_li", "size":200, "from":1580491663000, "to":1588184960000, "content_type":"stories"})
    r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = data).json()
    if r['articles'] != empty_list:
        articles_list = r["articles"]
        time.sleep(5)
        articles_list_normalized = json_normalize(articles_list)
        df = articles_list_normalized
        df['publication_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publication_timestamp'])
        df['publication_timestamp'] = df['publication_timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        df['citystate'] = city_name
        df = df.drop('has_video', 1)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = city_name)
writer.save()
```

Now `city_num_int = sub['id']` is a unique ID for different cities. Now the API returns a "videos" column for few cities and not for other. I want to get rid of that video column before it gets written to Excel file.

I was able to drop "has_video" column using `df.drop` as that column is present in each and every city data pull. But how do do conditional dropping for "videos" column as it is only present for few cities.

Comment: ```if 'videos' in df.columns``` to test before dropping or make a list of columns you want to retain and use ```loc``` instead of ```drop```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore the errors raised by Dataframe.drop:

```py
df = df.drop(['videos'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
```

Another way is to first check if column is present in DF, and only then delete it

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension on the column names to achieve what you want:

```
cols_to_keep = [c for c in df.columns if c != "videos"]
df = df[cols_to_keep]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This could be improved in two ways: first, you can simply subscribe to the list comprehension without assigning it to a variable. Second, if you intend to use the data frame and make further modifications, better make a `copy()`. This will avoid the infamous `SettingwithCopyWarning` as describe here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

```df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c != "videos"]].copy()```